# Error: cannot find symbol variable realm, cannot find symbol variable row

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to use Realm for my app. When I run, I get errors saying "cannot find symbol variable realm", and "cannot find symbol variable row" for every field in my model class

> error: cannot find symbol variable realm
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable row

Task.java

```
public class Task extends RealmObject {

  @PrimaryKey
  private int taskId;
  @Required
  private String taskName;
  private boolean completed;
  private Date date;

  //... auto-generated getters and setters

}
```

I also get the following two errors for the model class:

> error: TaskRealmProxy is not abstract and does not override abstract method realmGet$proxyState() in RealmObjectProxy
>
> error: TaskColumnInfo is not abstract and does not override abstract method copyColumnInfoFrom(ColumnInfo) in ColumnInfo

I tried with multiple model classed that extend RealmObject, and the errors seem to be the same with every class.

I also tried to Clean Project multiple times, but it did not solve the error.

In my build.gradle(project), I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
}
```

and in the build.gradle(app), I have added the following

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: Do you use obfuscation?

Comment: any other applied plugins? Do you by chance have a library project that also brings in an outdated version of Realm, for example `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I do use another library for realm recyclerview   `compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recycler-view:0.9.5'`

Comment: Yes, that library is out of date, it's recommended to use https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters instead and `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: Hey, @EpicPandaForce, would you make that an answer so the the OP can accept it?  That will make it so that the rest of the community can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any other applied plugins? Do you by chance have a library project that also brings in an outdated version of Realm, for example `RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter`? –

```
 compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recycler-view:0.9.5'
```

that library is out of date, it's recommended to use http://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters instead and `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`